# What are the best practices for consuming REST based WCF services from PHP?

Tags: c#, php, wcf, rest

We have a website built in PHP and are trying to enable it to talk to couple of services that are going to be written in WCF and follow REST Style architecture for web services.

Anybody have any best practices? issues?

Comment: I have to consume these webservices for one method, I have to send data to the service and from the other web method, I have to receive data. just additional fyi

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the WCF/C# aspect is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Not necessarily - depending on how the WCF service is configured he may or may not be able to use it at all with PHP.

Comment: It's hardly RESTful then, is it?

Comment: All he needs to know is that the REST calls are functioning correctly. Whether they originate from WCF or Java makes no difference.

By the way, referring to your other post, basicHttpBinding will create SOAP messages. I think he needs webHttpBinding for REST.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider configuring the WCF component to use the basicHTTPBinding.  Be mindful that it's possible to configure the WCF component so that you won't be able to access it at all with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) to retrieve a resource. If you need to manipulate it, you can use the [curl extension](http://www.php.net/curl). Curl also supports various forms of authentication.

You'll also need a parser to handle the resources. This will depend on the content-type, but XML is a common format and can be parsed with the [simplexml extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)